# Nested ElasticSearch query results in too many items

Tags: elasticsearch

The nested ElasticSearch query below returns some results it should not hit. A lot of results do not contain the requested order number but are listed nevertheless. I'm not getting all documents though so the query is definitely reducing the result set on some level.

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "orders",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "orderNumber": "242347"
        }
      }      
    }
  }
}
```

The query result (truncated):

```
{
  "took":0,
  "timed_out":false,
  "_shards": {
    "total":1,
    "successful":1,
    "failed":0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total":60,
    "max_score":9.656103,
    "hits":[
      {
        "_index": "index1",
        "_type":"documenttype1",
        "_id":"mUmudQrVSC6rn68ujDJ8iA",
        "_score":9.656103,
        "_source" : {
          "documentId": 12093894,
          "orders": [
          {
            "customerId": 129048669,
            "orderNumber": "242347", // <-- CORRECT HIT ON ORDER
          },
          {
            "customerId": 229405848,
            "orderNumber": "431962"
          }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index":"index1",
        "_type":"documenttype1",
        "_id":"9iO5QBCpT_6kmH3CoBTdWw",
        "_score":9.656103, 
        "_source" : {
          "documentId": 43390283,
          // <-- ORDER ISN'T HERE BUT THE DOCUMENT IS HIT NEVERTHELESS!
          "orders": [
          {
            "customerId": 229405848,
            "orderNumber": "431962"
          },
          {
            "customerId": 129408979,
            "orderNumber": "142701"
          }
          ]
        }
      }
      // Left out 58 more results most of which do not contain
      // the requested order number.
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, there is a hit (actually, there are quite a few of them) that shouldn't be there because none of the orders contain the requested order number.

This is the mapping for `documenttype1`:

```
{
   "index1":{
      "properties":{
         "documentId":{
            "type":"integer"
         },
         "orders":{
            "type":"nested",
            "properties":{
               "customerId":{
                  "type":"integer"
               },
               "orderNumber":{
                  "type":"string",
                  "analyzer":"custom_internal_code"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Finally, here are the settings to clarify the `custom_internal_code` analyzer as referred to in the mapping shown above:

```
{
   "index1":{
      "settings":{
         "index.analysis.analyzer.custom_internal_code.filter.1":"asciifolding",
         "index.analysis.analyzer.custom_internal_code.type":"custom",
         "index.analysis.analyzer.custom_internal_code.filter.0":"lowercase",
         "index.analysis.analyzer.custom_internal_code.tokenizer":"keyword",
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I do not know if that's related, but you should put the full path of the field in your query (i.e : orders.orderNumber)

Comment: @DeH: Thanks. I've verified that specifying the full path (`orders.orderNumber`) in the query doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Can you please add in your question a sample document that you feed in ES? I possibly have an explanation in my mind.

Comment: From the document, you must use full path for referenced fields in the query. So `orderNumber` should become `orders.orderNumber`

Answer (score 2):

for a exact search use termquery [1] and make orderNumber not_analyzed [2].

[1]
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html#query-dsl-term-query

[2]
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#_literal_index_literal

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should use bool query instead of match.

**But.** If you want just filter your records, your should use nested filter instead of query. It works faster, because you have not to calculate scores.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-filter.html

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "orders",
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "orderNumber": "242347"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "_cache": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to remove the outer "filtered" node to make it work. Sadly the results are the same as my query though.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting to use filtering though, that's useful information on its own.

Comment: `I had to remove the outer "filtered" node to make it work`. But it defines that filter would be applied. What message does ES show you when *filtered* node is presented?

Comment: If I leave it in, I get `Parse Failure [No parser for element [filtered]]]`. Perhaps this has to do with the fact that I'm posting this to `_search`?

Comment: Oh, yes. You should wrap it all in query.